# Create and Share bucket in google cloud storage using google api's

Tags: google-api, google-cloud-storage, postman, google-oauth

i need to create and share a bucket in gcloud storage using google api's. but i got an error  when am tring with postman(rest client).

Iam trying with

```
url 
-------
https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b?project=testproject

request body
------------
 {
   "name":"testbucketmanafnew"
 }
```

i got an error

```
{
  "error": {
    "errors": [
      {
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "required",
        "message": "Login Required",
        "locationType": "header",
        "location": "Authorization"
      }
    ],
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Login Required"
  }
}
```

after iam created an access tocken using OAuth 2.0 Playground. And added to header

```
Authorization = ya29.VALUE_REDACTED
```

But i got error

```
{
  "error": {
    "errors": [
      {
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "authError",
        "message": "Invalid Credentials",
        "locationType": "header",
        "location": "Authorization"
      }
    ],
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Invalid Credentials"
  }
}
```

what did i miss?

using Google api explorer, am able to call api's successfully

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b?project=testproject&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

{
 "name": "testmanafcjbucketyy"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Authorization needs to be passed in the following [format](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication#apiauth).

```
Authorization: Bearer [oauth2_token]
```

if you're using Postman the "Header" field becomes Authorization and the "Value" field becomes Bearer[WHITESPACE][oauth2_token]